# Using a Python script with Selenium on my cPanel

Tags: python, mysql, selenium, cron, cpanel

I have python script that I usually use on my PC. The script uses Selenium web driver, it collects data from a source, and stores it into my local MySQL db. I would like to automate it on my cPanel web-server instead of always running it from my PC and storing the data into my MySQL db in my cPanel. Maybe through a cron job. I'm using Selenium because, in order to collect my data, I need to complete input and select fields.

In short, I have no idea how to do this. I've never done this before and I feel like I'm running in circles trying to find out the best way to do it. Does anybody have any ideas or suggestions on where to get started? Many thanks!

Comment: "Maybe through a cron job!" yeah why not?

Comment: Well that's why I'm trying and not having any luck. @AminEtesamian

Comment: Its a good idea to append your not-working code